# Repassing unknown number of arguments

Tags: php, arguments

I have this little function that I use to call some functions in my class.

```
public static function call($method){
    $Model = new Model();
    if(method_exists($Model, $method)){
        return $Model->{$method}();
    }
}
```

Now, my question is about the args passed. I want to repass them, and I don't want an array to be passed, but the actual arguments.

I know the function func_get_arg() and func_num_args(), but this doesn't work:

```
$args = '';
for($i=0; $i<func_num_args(); $i++){
    $args .= func_get_args($i).',';
}

$args = substr($args, 0, strlen($args)-1);
```

Is there any alternative method i could call and pass in $Model->{$method}(passed_args)?

**UPDATE**

I tried altering the method to this, but it doesn't work:

```
public static function call($method){
    $Model = new Model();

    $args = func_get_args();
    if(method_exists($Model, $method)){
          return call_user_func_array(array($Model, $method), $args);
    }
}
```

It works if I do this, because until now I only have one arg or none:

```
public static function call($method, $args = null){
    $Model = new Model();

    if(method_exists($Model, $method)){
        return $Model->{$method}($args);
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

Of course I have to alter the method call:

```
public static function call(){
    $Model = new Model();

    $args = func_get_args();
    $method = array_shift($args);

    if(method_exists($Model, $method)){
        return call_user_func_array(array($Model, $method), $args);
    }
}
```

The above works. Thank you.

Comment: [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function foo() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    return call_user_func_array(array($model, $method), $args);
}
```